# If two random elements of list1 exists in list 2 , do that?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

How to make this condition with If_statament : "If two random elements of list1  exists in list2"

```
    cp1=[2,4,5,7,9,10,12,-2,-4,-5,-7,-9,-10,-12]

import itertools


for i in itertools.product((1,3,5,6,8,10,12), repeat=3) :
        i_suba1 = i[0] -  i[1]
        i_suba2 = i[0] -  i[2]
        i_subb1 = i[1] - i[2]



        allsub =  (i_suba1,  i_suba2, i_subb1)
        if  cp1 in allsub >=2 :# HERE, I WANT TO SAY " if two random elements of cp1 are in allsub print stuff"

              print (i,allsub)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am slightly unclear as to what you mean by random in "random elements" here, but I'm taking it to mean that you want to find out whether *any* two elements are shared by the two lists. This can be accomplished by finding the intersection of the two lists and seeing how large it is. There are [various methods to accomplish this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-intersection-two-lists/) but I would simply use a list comprehension:

```
intersection = [x for x in list1 if x in list2]
```

To test whether it meets your criteria you can then do `len(intersection) == 2` or `len(intersection) >= 2` depending on whether you want exactly two, or two or more, elements in both lists.

Comment: that's right, and  was exaclty what i found out haha
...
        allsub =  (i_suba1,  i_suba2, i_subb1)
        x= set(cp1).intersection(allsub)
   
        if len(x) ==2 :
                print (i,allsub)